# What do you call double consonants that are not affricates?

Tags: terminology, ipa, affricates

For example, the [IPA Help page for English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/English) lists these consonants:

> hw whine
> lj lute
> nj new
> sj consume
> θj enthuse
> zj Zeus

Is there a name to refer to this type of double consonants?

I'm thinking "double articulations" but I don't perceive it as quite accurate. Seems I could just say those as two consecutive consonants; it's the same ambiguity as for affricates:

> It is often difficult to decide if a stop and fricative form a single phoneme or a consonant pair.
> (Wikipedia)

Or maybe "consonant cluster", but now this seems too broad.

Comment: Doesn't it occur to you that the choice of the sound combinations on that Help page is caused by something? They didn't choose anything like /gr/ or /st/, or /bj/, but they do have /dj/, no /mj/, but there's /lj/ and /nj/. Why so? There's footnote symbol [**3**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/English#cite_note-yod-3) after the examples for the combinations of a consonant with /j/. Have you noticed it and read that and the other footnotes there? Don't they explain anything?

Comment: a side note: lj lute seems so strange to me, it's usually lute homophonous with loot.

Comment: @AlexB. - That's the reason why /lj/ and the like are singled out on that page as separate entities, they are the contexts where the phoneme /j/ can undergo [absolute neutralization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme#Neutralization_and_archiphonemes)

Comment: “There is always more than one way of looking at something, e.g. more than one way of interpreting a given set of facts. What this means for phonology is that for any set of data there will be more than one analysis available. One of the tasks facing the phonologist is therefore to evaluate competing analyses and to choose between them. In order to compare competing analyses and draw reasonable conclusions there are several issues to take into consideration, including evidence, **economy** and plausibility” (Davenport & Hannahs 2011, *Introducing Phonetics and Phonology*, p. 184; emphasis mine

Comment: and of course most importantly “The question of economy also applies to underlying inventories and specifications.” (p. 186)

Comment: So, these are merely consonant clusters

Comment: @AlexB. - Since you mentioned “more than one way of looking at something”, I can tell you about one more interpretation of those sound combinations. Have you ever noticed that after those cons. + [j] combinations only [u] can follow? _Only_. This is a sign that it's not that the cons. + [j] is an entity, but that [j]+[u] is. There's an interpretation of the English phonology in which there's a diphthong /i ̯u/ (/ju/) which is in variation with [u]/[uː], according to the dialect. As you can see, those are not _merely_ consonant clusters, there's something more behind them.

Comment: @YellowSky ah, I see what you're getting at. So, can you write a more detailed answer (including the proposed underlying form, positional variants, phonological rules at work etc.) and I will ask you more questions then?

Comment: @AlexB. - I don't think it's necessary to put it as an answer to this question, since that [ju] thing I mentioned affects not only the con.+[j] combinations mentioned on the IPA Help page, but the others, too, like [bj, vj, fj, mj, hj] etc. If you have questions, you can move this discussion to chat and we'll continue there.

Comment: @YellowSky I understand why they're found on the page. My question is about terminology.

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert - The aim of my first comment was to draw your attention to the rest of the content on that IPA Help page beside the transcription chart. You still haven't read it all up to diaphonemes.

Answer (score 8):

These are (mostly) consonant clusters and not reasonably analysed as single phonemes in English

For people who distinguish *wh* from *w* though, this is still a single consonant, /ʍ/ not a cluster /hw/. I.e. it is the voiceless counterpart of the usual labiovelar approximant /w/, not a sequence of /h/ and /w/

Double articulations would usually refer to phonemes produced in more than place of articulation simultaneously, e.g. /w/ or /ɡ͡b/ (both labial-velar)

Comment: Have you noticed and read footnote [3] on that Help page?

Comment: I don't see the relevance of yod-dropping/coalescence. The phonotactics are clear, the yod is either its own phoneme, or part of a single phoneme with the following vowel (as is its historical origin), not part of a single phoneme with the preceding consonant. This holds in all major dialects, whether yod-preserving, dropping, coalescing, or some combination

Comment: But is the number of phonemes in a morpheme of any relevance for you?

Comment: In your last sentence, it looks like you're saying that /w/ is doubly articulated? Is there a typo there?

Comment: @ruakh: not a typo, it says both articulations in the sentence: /w/ has both labial and velar articulations. The [IPA describes **w** as the "voiced labial-velar approximant"](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/sites/default/files/IPA_Kiel_2015.pdf); [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_labio-velar_approximant) says for some reason that [w] is specifically a "labialized velar" as opposed to a "true labial–velar" consonant

Comment: @brasstacks: \*facepalm\* Silly me. I understand now, thanks! :-)

Comment: @YellowSky I don't follow

Answer (score 5):

One reason why these are considered by some to be single segments is that they simplify to [w l n ...] in some dialects. There are sub-trends in phonology which treat consonant plus glide sequences as rounded or palatalized consonants. I am not persuaded by those claims, but that's not the question. If we assume that these are single segments, then the best standard term that unifies them is "complex". More often, we talk about them with a phrase, like "consonant with a secondary / vocalic articulation". "Double articulation is usually reserved for consonants with two primary articulations, such as kp, gb, and clicks. "Double consonant" is usually reserved for geminate consonants, which are two exactly same consonants, or a "long" consonant.

The evidence for the analysis of "hw" is very weak. It only appears where [h] can appear. It varies with plain w. There is also "hj" as in human, hubris. I know that some people pronounce human as "Yuman", so this simplification may be broader than just applying to h. The variable glide [j] in new is missing my dialect, but I have the voiceless or aspirated glides in white and human. The peculiar distribution of postcontinental palatal glides as in human, where the following vowel is always [u], has led some people to treat that as a diphthong [iu], so "new" would be [niu]. There is not a particularly strong reason to treat all of these consonant plus glide sequences the same way in English.

Answer (score 5):

As [the help page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/English) explains, the combinations of symbols you mentioned represent Wikipedia's own [**diaphonemes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaphoneme), not single [phonemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme) or [phones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_(phonetics)). They are listed separately because, *in that particular system*, e.g. /sj/ represents a unit that can be /sj/ (/s/ + /j/), /s/, or /ʃ/ depending on variety.